# How to make a div resizer with pure JAvaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a div resizer and due to some restrictions, I cannot use jQuery and I am forced to use pure JavaScript for that. In the current state, it works, but it breaks if the div that will have the slider does not have the position set to absolute. Is there a way to solve that issue? Thank you very much.

I am a student learning to write JavaScript/CSS/HTML code and so I am relatively new to this.

```js
const BORDER_SIZE = 4;
const panel = document.getElementById("left_panel");
const StationaryPanel = document.getElementById("right_panel");
const parent = document.getElementById("parent");

const label1 = document.getElementById("lb1");
const label2 = document.getElementById("lb2");
const label3 = document.getElementById("lb3");

let m_pos;

function resize(e) {
  const dx = m_pos - e.x;
  m_pos = e.x;

  lb1.innerHTML = panel.offsetWidth;
  lb2.innerHTML = StationaryPanel.offsetWidth;
  lb3.innerHTML = parent.offsetWidth;
  //lb3.innerHTML = document.body.clientWidth;

  panel.style.width = (parseInt(getComputedStyle(panel, '').width) + dx) + "px";
  StationaryPanel.style.width = (parent.offsetWidth - panel.offsetWidth) + "px";
  //StationaryPanel.style.width = (document.body.clientWidth - panel.offsetWidth) + "px";
}

panel.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  if (e.offsetX < BORDER_SIZE) {
    m_pos = e.x;
    if (panel.style.width < panel.minWidth || panel.style.width > panel.maxWidth) {
      return;
    }
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", resize, false);
  }
}, false);

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize, false);
}, false);
```

```css
#left_panel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 96px;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0ff;
}

#left_panel::before {
  content: " ";
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: w-resize;
}

#right_panel {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#parent {
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="left_panel">
      This is the left div, the one that moves
    </div>
    <div id="right_panel">
      This is the right div, the one that stays the same
    </div>
  </div>


  <p id="lb1"></p>
  <p>This is the left panel width ^</p>
  <p id="lb2"></p>
  <p>This is the right panel width ^</p>
  <p id="lb3"></p>
  <p>This is the parent width ^</p>
</body>
```

Comment: so you need resizer to be done on side ways?

Comment: Yes. I need the left panel to be the main one that resizes and then has an effect over the second right panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest way you can do it using `CSS` if that is not an issue here no need to use JS for this feature, it is just an example but it definitely help you on your way.

```css
#MainDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

#leftDiv {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

#rightDiv {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  /* you can make this vertical/auto to make resize both ways */
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="MainDiv">
  <div id="leftDiv">
    Left Div
  </div>
  <div id="rightDiv">
    Right Div
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is it in Javascript:

```js
var h = $('#handle'),
  l = $('#left'),
  r = $('#right'),
  w = $('body').width() - 18;

var isDragging = false;

h.mousedown(function(e) {
  isDragging = true;
  e.preventDefault();
});
$(document).mouseup(function() {
  isDragging = false;
}).mousemove(function(e) {
  if (isDragging) {
    l.css('width', e.pageX);
    r.css('width', w - e.pageX);
  }
});
```

```css
#left,
#right {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 48%;
}

#handle {
  background: #000;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1px;
  /* Slider width */
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left"> Left</div>
<div id="handle"></div>
<div id="right">Right</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. There are two reasons why I am not going with this method. The website that i am planing to implement this to does not support this feature (do not know why) and I need a bar that runs along the full height of the div block not just in the corner

Comment: Yeah got it! I added one more snippet check that it may be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you. This still uses the JQuerry. Could you maybe just point out what the issue with my code is? Why changing the position from absolute just breaks it?

Comment: That is the property of `absolute` so tell me why using `absolute` is not an option for you?

Comment: It works. After multiple websites and reading I understand that the **absolute** property goes hand in hand with the relative and that the parent div must have it set. That solved my issue, thank you very much for your time and examples! If you have anything more to add please do so.

Comment: I am glad I was able to give you my 2 cents ideas, yes you always place `relative` for parent and make child `absolute`, I thought to look into your code to fix that! glad it worked. I will keep this code that some one can look into resizer for javascript and css :P kindly vote if you think if it is worth voting!.